# Where is bundle.js of react project

Tags: reactjs

I created a project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app),it can run correctly at http://localhost:3000,
but I need set cross domain with nginx,the config of nginx is as follow:

```
server {
    listen       3001;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /api { 
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.33.3:8080;    
    }  

    location ~ \.(htm|html|js|css|jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {  
        root    html;     
    }    

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```

Accessing `localhost:3001` in chrome,there is an error:

[image]
[image]

I can not find `bundle.js` in project folder,so how to fix this problem?

Comment: By default CRA names the js file something like `main.*randomcharacters*.js`. Which is located at `/build/static/js/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use nginx instead of dev server you need to build your CRA project and copy build folder content to your root HTML path

```
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         html;

    location /api { 
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.33.3:8080;    
    }   

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```